# Prisma queries: Argument type .. is not assignable to parameter type SelectSubSet

Tags: reactjs, next.js, webstorm, prisma, jetbrains-ide

I'm using Next.js and Prisma for my current project but in my IDE (WebStorm currently), I am constantly getting the same warning on most CRUD queries in Prisma.

**This is only in JetBrains WebStorm however, if I open the project in VSCode the warning disappears...**

This is what the warning looks like:

[image]

This is what the full `bookingInput` passed to the create function looks like:

```
bookingInput {
  start_date: '2023-11-10T15:05:52.541Z',
  end_date: '2023-11-10T19:05:52.541Z',
  number_of_guests: 2,
  price: 240,
  venue: { connect: { id: 'venue-0' } },
  customer: { connect: { id: 'user-41' } }
}
```

And this is its `BookingCreateInput` type:

```
  export type BookingCreateInput = {
    id?: string
    booking_date?: Date | string
    start_date: Date | string
    end_date: Date | string
    number_of_guests: number
    host_notes?: string | null
    price?: Decimal | DecimalJsLike | number | string | null
    paid?: boolean
    venue?: VenueCreateNestedOneWithoutBookingsInput
    customer?: UserCreateNestedOneWithoutBookingsInput
  }
```

And finally, this is my Prisma Schema:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id         String    @id @db.VarChar(36) @default(uuid())
  email      String
  password   String
  first_name String
  last_name  String
  role       USER_ROLE @default(CUSTOMER)
  bookings   Booking[]
  ratings    Rating[]
  venues     Venue[]

  @@map("users")
}

model Venue {
  id                      String        @id @db.VarChar(36) @default(uuid())
  name                    String        @db.VarChar(50)
  description             String        @db.MediumText
  capacity                Int
  surface_area            Decimal       @db.Decimal(4, 0)
  hourly_price            Decimal       @db.Decimal(5, 0)
  opening_time            DateTime      @db.Time(4)
  closing_time            DateTime      @db.Time(4)
  status                  VENUE_STATUS  @default(PENDING)
  is_featured             Boolean?      @default(false)
  location_street         String
  location_number         String
  location_city           String
  location_zip_code       String
  location_state_province String
  location_country        String
  location_lat            Decimal       @default(0)
  location_lng            Decimal       @default(0)
  bookings                Booking[]
  ratings                 Rating[]
  activities              Activity[]
  facilities              Facility[]
  styles                  Style[]
  host_id                 String?  @db.VarChar(36)
  host                    User?    @relation(fields: [host_id], references: [id], onUpdate: NoAction)

  @@map("venues")
}

model Style {
  id           Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  name         String
  venues       Venue[]

  @@map("styles")
}

model Facility {
  id               Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name             String
  venues           Venue[]

  @@map("facilities")
}

model Activity {
  id               Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name             String
  venues           Venue[]

  @@map("activities")
}

model Booking {
  id               String   @id @db.VarChar(36) @default(uuid())
  booking_date     DateTime @default(now())
  start_date       DateTime
  end_date         DateTime
  number_of_guests Int
  host_notes       String?
  price            Decimal? @db.Decimal(4, 0)
  paid             Boolean  @default(false)
  venue_id         String?  @db.VarChar(36)
  customer_id      String?  @db.VarChar(36)
  venue            Venue?   @relation(fields: [venue_id], references: [id], onUpdate: NoAction)
  customer         User?    @relation(fields: [customer_id], references: [id], onUpdate: NoAction)

  @@map("bookings")
}

model Rating {
  id              String  @id @db.VarChar(36) @default(uuid())
  rating          Int
  review          String?
  would_recommend Boolean
  reviewer_id     String? @db.VarChar(36)
  venue_id        String? @db.VarChar(36)
  user            User?   @relation(fields: [reviewer_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: NoAction)
  venue           Venue?  @relation(fields: [venue_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: NoAction)

  @@map("ratings")
}

enum USER_ROLE {
  ADMIN
  CUSTOMER
  HOST
}

enum VENUE_STATUS {
  PENDING
  APPROVED
  DECLINED
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems like a problem from Prisma ORM plugin on JetBrains. This warning disappears after disabling Prisma ORM plugin. You should probably report this issue to the JetBrains team as they are the author of that plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I got similar error in WebStorm. Disappeared after adding Prisma plugin.